# Calling one GrpcService from other using dependency injection

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, grpc, grpc-java

I have two grpc service in same project built using spring boot. And I am trying to call Y service in X service using autowiring but I am not able to pass required StreamObserver to the Y service method.

Below is the code.

**XService.java**

```
@GrpcService
public class XService extends XServiceImplBase {

@Autowired
YService yService;

@Override
public void getInfo(RequestId request, StreamObserver<Info> responseObserver) {

    // Not abe to pass the second argument here
    yService.getData(request, <observer>);

 }
}
```

**YService.java**

```
@GrpcService
public class YService extends YServiceImplBase {

 @Override
 public void getData(RequestId request, StreamObserver<Data> responseObserver) {
    // Code Logic
 }
}
```

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a client with same name as server in application.properties and call with stub. Worked for me